# Baofeng uv-5r,uv-82. i need disable or block side key moni(monitor) for don´t listen private cts dts

Tags: baofeng

I need to disable or block the side key moni(monitor) so others can't hear on my private CTS DTS.  I use a Baofeng UV-5R and a UV-82. Another team that uses the same repeater, but has different CTS DTS codes, can hear when I press the side key moni.

Comment: Related: [Receiving without configuring CTCSS](http://ham.stackexchange.com/q/5295/29) and [Can two FM radios transmit two separate PL tones at the same time, and be received by two radios with matching PL tones?](http://ham.stackexchange.com/q/1797/29)

Comment: Just don't press the button, then.  And always remember that everybody can still hear your transmit, whether or not you use any kind of tones.

Answer (score 6):

Don't bother.

**CTCSS tones are not an effective privacy mechanism.** Anyone at all with a FM two-way radio or scanner can receive your transmissions; attempting to prevent this by locking down your radios gives you only the *illusion* of privacy.

(P.S. This site is for *Amateur Radio*, and I'm guessing you're actually a commercial radio user. I'm answering your question anyway because I think it's close enough to being about the technology in general and Baofeng radios are commonly used by amateur license holders as well.)

Comment: I totally agree with @Kevin, and would only add that the only way to disable it would be to take an X-acto knife and cut off the rubber part.  But then there goes any kind of water resistance.  So I echo:  Don't bother.

Answer (score 2):

CTCSS tones or DTS digital tones, are only for "Receiving intended signals".

If a receiver is configured to receive on a frequency with CTCSS or DTS, then the squelch is only opening when the transmitted signal contains the "matching" CTCSS or DTS.

If a signal is transmitted without the "matching" CTCSS or DTS, then the receiver's squelch will not open, and you will not hear the signal.

However, if a receiver is configured on a frequency without CTCSS or DTS, then it will receive all signals, including those which have CTCSS or DTS, and the squelch will open.

So, if you are communicating on a frequency with many many users, you can transmit with CTCSS/DTS, and receive with the same CTCSS/DTS, and you will only hear these signals....

However, everyone else; with receivers configured without CTCSS/DTS... will also hear your transmitted signal!

This is why it is a "false/illusion of privacy" as answered already.

Use CTCSS/DTS only if you want to **restrict a receiver to a specific transmitted signal**, with the understanding that **others can perfectly receive your signal**.

HTH.